# Can I set up 'message content' Events to be exported and then imported to my index (discord.js)?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, event-handling, bots

I am still learning discord.js and am currently wondering if there is a way to set up "Events" (or maybe I'm looking for the word "Arguments") for 'message content' type commands.

My end goal is just to clean up all my if/else if statements, and since I just learned about SlashCommands, I was wondering if I could build something similar without needing the added "/".

Here is my Event Handler in the index.js module:

```
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
            await interaction.followUp({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        } else {
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a very simple command example I'm wanting to turn *into* an Event to then "module.exports":

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {

    if(message.content === 'Testing Message Event') {
        message.reply('Message Event Tested');
    };
};
```

Here is a simple Event example I made from a tutorial under a 'botIsOnline' module:

```
const { Events } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.ClientReady,
    once: true,
    execute(client) {
        console.log('♥ Bot is Online');
    },
};
```

I haven't been able to find much about *what* I can put under "module.exports," so I don't know how or *if* I can format 'messageCreate' commands as events...sorry if this is a silly question and/or if I just missed/misunderstood documentation!!!

Oh, in terms of what I've tried... I have basically just tried templating the SlashCommandBuilder module exports and tried replacing classes with Events, Clients, MessageEvents, etc...

Like this:

```
const { Client, Events, Guild } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {

    name: Events.MessageContent,
    if: 'hello',
    execute(client) {
        console.log('trying event hello');
    },
};
```

Haha, but obviously it is not doing anything;;;
There are no errors but also no outcomes either. I really just don't know how to set it up. Thank you for any and all help, and please don't mind my silly little brain.

Comment: Are you sure (in your last example) you've got the right event? The docs show that it's `Events.MessageCreate`, not `Events.MessageContent` which would explain why your event is not firing in your last example! See https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/Events